# Access another xml within same folder from spring-servlet.xml

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to access another xml within same folder from spring-servlet.xml

```
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"
  p:config-location="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
```

On executing the spring-servlet.xml file, I get resource not found exception. How can I get the path for the file "ehcache.xml" within the same folder as spring-servlet.xml.

Comment: try: `classpath:/ehcache.xml`

Comment: What is the location of your `ehcache.xml`/`spring-servlet.xml`?

Comment: You can give WEB-INF/src/ehcache.xml...if you are placing ehcache under web-inf/src....if it is within the same folder try ./ehcache.xml

Comment: @Jens I tried that, but no result.

Comment: @rockydgeekgod Location for ehcache.xml is WebContent/WEB-INF

Comment: @AarikGowda using ./ehcache.xml did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access using `p:config-location="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"` if your both xml are in WEB-INF folder

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" p:config-location="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"/>
```

Comment: @Dinesh similar answer i posted in comment!!